# Get laravel route {slug} in middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing role based access system in laravel, i want to validate each request thorugh moddileware. So i want to my route **{slug}** in my middleware, based on that slug i want to check that user has permission for access that request. How can i achieve that?

My route code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'testmiddleware'], function ($router) {
        Route::get('{slug}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});
```

Comment: it is solved..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add prefix to group

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => "{slug}", 'middleware' => 'testmiddleware'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@getAuthenticatedUser'); // it will geneate url {slug}
    Route::get('blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\Blog@getBlogs');// it will geneate url {slug}/blog
    Route::post('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Users@getUsers'); // it will geneate url {slug}/user
});
```

then in middleware you will get

```php
$request->slug
```

- in this way you will get `slug` to all group no need to add all the routes

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: I have multiple routes can i get all routes slug by using above code?

Comment: Hi it's not working in my side,
 Route::post('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Blog@getBlogs');
Route::post('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Users@getUsers');
every time it calls getBlogs controller

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say, can you please edit your answer for multiple routes

Answer (score 4):

If you want get the value of the **{slug}** parameter in the route within your **testmiddleware**, you can achieve that as following:

```
$request->route('slug')
```